# How can I get the right selector (CSS/XPath) to use with Scrapy?

Tags: css, xpath, scrapy, selector, screen-scraping

I want to scrape information from this site: https://www.atl.no/finn-trafikkskole?limit=0&limitstart=0 (a national list of driving schools) to map zip codes and company names on a map (I've already got the mapping from zip codes to coordinates) to find areas with a significant concentration of schools. An optimal result would be a selector that extracts all the relevant information of each of the 710 companies ([all relevant information of each company](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS4Bl.png))

[Highlighted zip code of the first driving school](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMqlF.png)

I've tried copying both CSS "selector" and XPath of the wanted table ([table as in Chrome DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Argym.png)) but when running the CSS selector/XPath in Scrapy it returns nothing.

Example of the copied CSS selector that gives nothing when ran in a Scrapy shell:

In(1): `response.css("#adminForm > table > tbody").extract()`

Out(1): `[]`

What have I done wrong and how should I proceed to get the wanted result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on page structure I would split the parsing job as follows:

```py
    def extract_text(self, item):
        text = item.get()
        text = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', text)
        return text

    def parse(self, response):
        for school in response.css('.uk-table tr'):

            yield {
                'address': self.extract_text(school.css('.school-address')),
                'school': school.css('tr > td > a::text').get(),
            }
```

Comment: When running my program with your code I get the error: 

_"AttributeError: 'schoolSpider' object has no attribute 'extract_text'"_ . When commenting out the bit with 'address' I get school names as _{'school': '#'}_

Comment: Check the update: added the missing extract_text and fixed the syntax coloring. extract_text needs some updates to clean the HTML tags and to extract only the needed lines

Answer (score 0):

`#adminForm > table > tbody` returns empty results because `tbody` is tag automatically added by browsers like Firefox and Chrome.

But when scraping with Scrapy, `tbody` was not there in the response HTML.

See source of page: view-source:https://www.atl.no/finn-trafikkskole?limit=0&limitstart=0

See Scrapy talks about tbody tag
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom